# JS dynamically generate table of contents with page numbers for printing

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, printing

I'm trying to build a version of a website in a way that can be cleanly printed to pdf. The original site is built in ReactJS so I'm reusing the components I need in the correct layout for the pdf document. (the pdf needs to look very similar to the website).

The pdf will consist of:

- Front cover
- Table of contents
- [...customer pages]
- Closing cover

I have a db table with various customer details (dynamic) which is looped over to generate the customer pages at run time.
The bulk of the work is done. The only thing remaining is the table of contents.

The problem is that the table of contents needs to have a list of the customers, with the page number that customer is located on.

I've been researching for an hour a day for a few days now but there doesn't seem to be an appropriate way of doing this since the page numbers don't seem to be known until the user actually ties to print the document.

Is there a way to determine the page a specific element will appear on when being printed?

Comment: Are you using a specific library to generate the pdf? A hacky way that comes to mind is to get the height of elements you are including and add them up. You can then compare the obtained value with respect to the height of a page to increment a page counter.

Comment: Which component do you use for creating pdf file, if you dont use any specific pdf library, then you can generate as html and css.

Comment: You can use pagedjs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [PDFMAKE](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.3/).
Here is the npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake

It produces the following:

- table of contents
- you can make front cover and back cover
- any customer pages can also be accomplished

Regarding getting the correct pages that a customer will be mentioned on, you will probably need to generate the entire PDF minus the table of contents and then insert that in after so that you can create a temporary object during loop that holds the valid mapping between customer to page number.